# I have a <div> that moves an element on the page instead of increase it's size, how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css

I have a YouTube video inside of a `<div>` on my web page. When I Ctrl+ (increase text size), it moves around on the page instead of simply increasing it's size like all of my other `<divs>` do...what are some of the reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you use pixels to size your elements. Some browsers just 'zoom in', giving no problems. Others (like IE) increase sizes of elements, but then 15 pixels will always be 15 pixels. Try setting sizes in percentages or em's.

- http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

(most of what's being said about font sizes applies to other elements as well)

Comment: But wouldn't that mean going in and changing all of the values I have set to pixels to sizes in percentages, then testing again? There's not an easier fix for this? If not, what a nightmare. Thanks for the reply back.

Comment: I also  noticed that when I use Ctrl + my "elements" go inward on the page. I think if I could get them to go outward on the page that would help. I'm grasping at straws here so...not sure.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to help you with that without the code. If you post a link to an example and un-check the answer I'll look at it tomorrow during worktime :P